# XSL : how to obtain the result of two different match

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm willing to create an XSL Document that modifies the attribute of a root nodes, but that is also capable of changing the content of the XML document.

Here is my XSL Document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ns="some:ns">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<ns:WhiteList>
    <name>HEADER</name>
    <name>ROOTNODE</name>
    <name>foo</name>
    <name>bar</name>
    <name>toto</name>
</ns:WhiteList>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROOTNODE[@xsi:id = 'myXSDFile.xsd'] ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:id ">myXSDFCleansedFile.xsd</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ROOTNODE[@xsi:id = 'myXSDFile.xsd']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my input XML document is the following one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOTNODE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:id="myXSDFile.xsd">
    <HEADER>
        ....
    </HEADER>
    <foo>blabla</foo>
    <bar>blabla</bar>
    <tab>dada</tab>
    <toto>blabla</toto>
    <titi>blabla</titi>
</ELIX>
```

The output I obtained is either :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOTNODE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:id="myXSDFileCleansed.xsd">
```

Or :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOTNODE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:id="myXSDFile.xsd">
    <HEADER>
        ....
    </HEADER>
    <foo>blabla</foo>
    <bar>blabla</bar>
    <toto>blabla</toto>
</ROOTNODE>
```

But the problem is that I want the second output, but with the xsd file name changed ! And I didn't succeed in merging the two different match paths. Do you have any idea how to merge the two match paths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get what you exactly tried. But first, if you wan't children processed when you apply your xsl, try to replace:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="ROOTNODE[@xsi:id = 'myXSDFile.xsd']"/>`

with
`<xsl:apply-templates/>`

When you are in the template, the context is `ROOTNODE` and when you try to apply template to `"ROOTNODE[...]"`, the processor is looking for children of the context named `ROOTNODE`.